# Можно ли как то получить Request Headers через node-fetch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

При каждом запросе, сервер, к которому обращаюсь, к моему запросу сам ставит header заголовок `x`.

Могу ли я как-нибудь его получить?

Answer (score 2):

В объекте `Response` есть read-only атрибут [`headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/headers), по которому можно получить доступ к объекту [`Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers).

От объекта `Headers` можно вызвать метод [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/get), передав ему имя заголовка.

> response.headers.get(name);

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.headers.get('cache-control'));
    console.log(response.headers.get('x'));
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((json) => console.log(json))
```

Answer (score 0):

По идее так:

```
fetch('https://stackoverflow.com/')
.then(res => {
    console.log(res.headers.get('x-header'));
});
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#accessing-headers-and-other-meta-data